# Jquery UI Tabs Enable/Disable events not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I am trying to toggle a series of navigation buttons to react when I disable/enable tabs. However the tabs enable and disable methods don't seem to be firing them (or perhaps the binding is wrong).

This works:

```
$('body').on('tabsload', '.tabContainer', function (event, ui) {
   $(ui.panel).find(".tab-loading").remove();
});
```

This does not work:

```
$('body').on('tabsenable', '.tabContainer', function (event, ui) {
   debugger;
});
$('body').on('tabsdisable', '.tabContainer', function (event, ui) {
   debugger;
});
```

I am enabling the tabs this way:

```
$tabContainer.tabs('option', 'disabled', []);
```

Does this not fire an event? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is set the option **disabled** and not call a method.

Try this:

```
$(".tabContainer").tabs('enable');
$(".tabContainer").tabs('disable');
```

And:

```
$(".tabContainer").bind("tabsenable", function(event, ui){
    // action...
});

$(".tabContainer").bind("tabsdisable", function(event, ui){
    // action...
});
```

Comment: I've tried that, but nothing fires:
      $tabContainer.bind("tabsenable", function (event, ui) { debugger; });
      $tabContainer.tabs('enable');

Comment: Ok this seems to work, but its ridiculous that I cannot enable more tabs than one at a time: $tabContainer.tabs('enable', 1);

Comment: Without the second parameter was expected to enable/disable all tabs. If this is not working, something strange happened.

Comment: Well the rest of the internet seems to support you, something strange must be going on.